# i cannot install nodemon in npm nodejs

Tags: node.js

i can not install nodemon it has problem with npm

Vus-MacBook-Air:nodejs vuvantuu$ sudo npm install -g nodemon
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/vuvantuu/.npm/_logs/2019-08-08T07_07_43_043Z-debug.log

Comment: `sudo npm i -g nodemon`. Or if you don't want to do it via root user - check [npm install global without sudo](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md)

Comment: you could also keep nodemon locally in your project, and access it by npm run script

Answer (score 1):

You must be required administrative privileges to install anything,
you can use

> sudo npm install -g nodemon

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

As the error says - you don't have write access to the `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` folder.

The simplest way to get rid of this error - is to run the command via `sudo`

`sudo npm i -g nodemon`

---

But if you don't want to run it via `root` user for any reasons (e.g security) you could install packages globally for a given user.

1. Create a directory for global packages

```sh
mkdir "${HOME}/.npm-packages"
```

2. Tell `npm` where to store globally installed packages

```sh
npm config set prefix "${HOME}/.npm-packages"
```

3. Ensure `npm` will find installed binaries and man pages

Add the following to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`:

```sh
NPM_PACKAGES="${HOME}/.npm-packages"

export PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"

# Unset manpath so we can inherit from /etc/manpath via the `manpath` command
unset MANPATH # delete if you already modified MANPATH elsewhere in your config
export MANPATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man:$(manpath)"
```

> NOTE: If you are running macOS, the `.bashrc` file may not yet exist, and the terminal will be obtaining its environment parameters from another file, such as `.profile` or `.bash_profile`. These files also reside in the user's home folder. In this case, simply adding the following line to them will instruct Terminal to also load the `.bashrc` file:

```sh
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: thank you so much